# Do I need the following measure-theory properties to prove one of the conditions for $d_p$ distance to be a metric on $L^p(X)$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

In the book Linear functional analysis by Rynne and Youngson, Second edition:

**Definition 1.17** If d is a metric the following conditions hold:

(...)

(b) $d(x, y) = 0 \iff x = y$

(...)

**Theorem 1.52**

Let $(X, Σ, d\mu )$ be a measure space and let $f \in  \mathcal{L}^1(X)$.

(a) If $f(x) = 0$ a.e., then $f \in  \mathcal{L}^1(X)$ and $\int_X f d\mu  = 0$.

(c) If $f, g \in \mathcal{L}^1(X)$ and $f(x) ≤ g(x)$ for all $x \in  X$, then $\int_X f d\mu ≤ \int_X g d\mu $.
If, in addition, $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \in  S$, with $µ(S) > 0$, then $\int_X f d\mu  <
\int_X g d\mu $.

**Corollary 1.56**

b) The function

$d_p(f, g) =( \int_X |f-g|^p d\mu)^{1/p}$, for $1\ge p < \infty$ and

$d_p(f, g) =\text{ess sup |f-g|}$, for $ p = \infty$

is a metric on $L^p(X)$ (condition (b) in Definition 1.17 follows from properties (a) and (c) in Theorem 1.52, together with the construction of the spaces $L^p(X)$)

**I have a doubt with this, I 'dont see why property (c) is needed to proof $d_p(f, g) = 0 \iff f = g$**

My proof:

1. for $ p\in [1,\infty) )$

If $( \int_X |f-g|^p d\mu)^{1/p} =0 \implies |f-g|^p =0  \text{ a.e} \implies f=g \text{ a.e} \implies f \equiv g$  , since they belong to the same class

If $f\equiv g \implies |f-g|^p =0 \text{ a.e}$, so$\implies$ (using (1.52 a))$( \int_X |f-g|^p d\mu)^{1/p} =0$

2. for $p=\infty$

If $0={\text{ess sup} |f-g| } = \text{inf}\{C\ge 0 ; |f(x)-g(x)|\le 0 \text{ a.e}  \}$
$\implies |f(x)-g(x)|\le 0 \text{ a.e} \implies f=g \text{ a.e} \implies f \equiv g $

If $f=g \implies \text{ess sup}(|f-g|) =\text{ess sup}(0) =0$ since the smallest $C \ge 0$ such that $0 \le C$ is $C=0$

**So where is (c) needed? Is my proof correct? Is there is anything that is not written preciselly Or where property (a) should have been called please tell me as well**

Comment: How do you prove that $\int |f|\,d\mu=0$ implies $f=0$ $\mu$-a.e.?

Comment: @MaoWao I take as a property of the Lebesgue integral for positive functions. The book does not give it, though, so perhaps this is where 1.52c can be used  ?

Comment: That's exactly what you get from (c): As $|f|\geq 0$, $|f|>0$ on a set of positive measure implies $\int |f|\,d\mu>0$.

Comment: @MaoWao But I need the opposite implication and with a = sign : start from the integral being 0 and then get that the integrant is 0 a.e,

Comment: Well, that's just the contraposition of the statement from (c).

Comment: @MaoWao I see, great, thanks, is this the only point where I need it? Does the rest look ok?